# Firebase Cloud Functions in Golang

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Is it possible to write Firebase Cloud Functions in Golang such that they can access Firebase services such as Firestore and Storage, in **both production and emulators**?

Ideally I would like to have a http triggered function that read from and writes to Firestore and Storage while taking advantage of Firebase pricing and the emulators suite.

I know that it is possible to create serverless functions using Cloud Run but that does not give me the ability to interact with local emulators. I would also like to colocate this function with my other typescript functions.

Answer (score 1):

The only currently supported language to write firebase functions in is JavaScript. See:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions

Comment: Not entirely true, there is a Python functions library, but it's a "poorly kept secret" as they put it. I'm hoping there's another secret workaround to functions in Go.

Comment: Secret -> Not yet launched

Comment: The 2nd gen of Cloud Functions now supports Python as announced at Google I/O 2023
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?gen=2nd

Answer (score 0):

You can use Go to write Firebase Cloud Functions.

Here are some documentation that you may find useful and that you can follow and replicate in order to deploy projects in Firebase using Golang:

- [Add the Firebase Admin SDK to your server](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup/#go)
- [firebase-admin-go github](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go)
- [Firebase: Developing serverless functions in Go](https://medium.com/google-cloud/firebase-developing-serverless-functions-in-go-963cb011265d)